# Trigger a script using Wake-on-LAN on Windows 10

Tags: automation, windows-10, wake-on-lan

I have recently enabled wake-on-LAN on my PC running the latest version of Windows 10. Can a script (or any other means of automation) be set up so that each time my PC wakes from LAN (and *only* on wake from LAN), it will automatically open a specified webpage?

I am lazy and I want to sent a wake-on-LAN from my Android smartphone while on my bed. I want my PC to then start playing a wake-up playlist on YouTube, without me pressing any more buttons.

Comment: The answer to your question is "Probably". If you want to know how, feel free to attempt it yourself, then come back here with the problems that, no matter how hard you try, you can't figure out how to solve.

Comment: Maybe you should see if you can trigger a Scheduled Task based on the WoL event to do what you want instead.

Comment: So just to add the progress i made and some other info. The pc autologins at boot to a non admin hotmail user account.
My first approach was to create a shortcut of the url on the desktop and load it using windows Task Scheduler. I couldn't find a specific parameter to use it on wol so i had it to lanch the shortcut at boot firsts, then at user logon both without success. Then i elevated the account to admin but still no luck. Finally i replaced the shortcut with a batch script and that too failed. My workaround is to have the batch scrip shortcut on the system startup folder. Any suggestions?